# Parsing input for table automatically generated from csv file

Tags: tables, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I have a .csv file which looks like:

```
{one},{two},{three}
11/07/2014,14:49:54,(100,100)
2,2,2
```

I have some code which creates a table from the .csv file.

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% Setup siunitx:
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places, % Rounds numbers
  round-precision     = 2, % to 2 places
}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
 \caption{Autogenerated table from .csv file.}
\label{table1}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  multicolumn names, % allows to have multicolumn names
  col sep=comma, % the seperator in our .csv file
  display columns/0/.style={
    column name=$Value 1$, % name of first column
    column type={S},string type},  % use siunitx for formatting
  display columns/1/.style={
    column name=$Value 2$,
    column type={S},string type},
  display columns/1/.style={
    column name=$Value 3$,
    column type={S},string type},
  every head row/.style={
    before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
    after row={
      \si{\ampere} & \si{\volt} & \si{\tesla} \\ % the units seperated by &
        \midrule} % rule under units
        },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}, % rule at bottom
]{/path/to/file/table.csv} % filename/path to file
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Taken from this [tutorial](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/advanced/latex-pgfplotstable/)

However, I get errors for every csv cell where I have either a "," or a ":".

Which read:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '(100,100)'
|75 error| Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '00:04:00'
```

I've tried the usual suspects by wrapping the cells in "" or {} but to no avail.

Comment: Your MWE is missing a `\begin{document}`.  Is `column type={S}` the right thing to be using?  As I understand this expects a single number (to align on decimal point) which is definitely not true in this example.  From what I can see it is the `(100,100)` entry alone causing trouble, unfortunately I agree the usual escapes don't work, `{14:49:54}` seems to fix the erros on the second entry in that line though.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used comment to point things out, but I cannot yet; though this is no complete answer yet…

When I minimize your example and make it compile (document does not begin anywhere yet), I get to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
{one},{two},{three}
11/07/2014,14:49:54,(100,100)
2,2,2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
% Setup siunitx:
\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2 }
\pgfplotstableread[
  multicolumn names, % allows to have multicolumn names
  col sep=comma, % the seperator in our .csv file
  display columns/0/.style={
    column name=$Value 1$, % name of first column
    column type={S},string type},
  display columns/1/.style={
    column name=$Value 2$,
    column type={S},string type},
  display columns/1/.style={
    column name=$Value 3$,
    column type={S},string type},
  every head row/.style={
    before row={\toprule}, % have a rule at top
    after row={
  \si{\ampere} & \si{\volt} & \si{\tesla} \\
    \midrule} % rule under units
    },
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{table.csv} …
\end{document}
```

It then results in the helpful error message:

> Package pgfplots Error: Table 'table.csv' appears to have too many columns in
>    line 5: Ignoring '100)'. PGFPlots found that the number of columns is larger t
>   han the previously determined number of columns. Please verify that every cell
>   entry is separated correctly (use braces {} if necessary. Also veri
>   fy that column names are plain ASCII.). This error is not critical.

Next I suggest

- replace the coordinate delimiter with sth. else than comma (which is in use for the csv) or
- replace the comma for cell separation with e.g. semicolon

Also consider next time:

- create minimal working example (often referred to as MWE)
- and make it in a single file (see filecontents)

because the pros (that might be able to help you instantly) do not waste their time on doing that for you.